# Get a href url link for a pdf or csv download from a nginx server

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, nginx, xmlhttprequest

I want to download a csv or pdf file from this webpage.

Where can I find the download url?

**I have the onClick link address from the network inspection.**

https://***.***.***.***/OA_HTML/OA.jsp?page=/oracle/apps/pos/orders/webui/PosVpoMainPG&_ri=177&OASF=POS_PURCHASE_ORDERS&OAMC=75556_101_0&searchType=advancedSearch&fwkQBSearchTypeSource=/oracle/apps/pos/orders/webui/PosVpoMainPG__QueryRN__177&fwkST/oracle/apps/pos/orders/webui/PosVpoMainPG__BuyerQueryRN__177=search&_ti=929717154&retainAM=Y&addBreadCrumb=N&oapc=5&oas=y3U6e-azV0PHjxYBLKMvDQ..

I've made a few requests with the XMLHTTP object in VBScript.

```
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

But i'm not sure how to process the headers.

I have the request and response headers.

**Response:**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 37725
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=PO_700501602.pdf
Content-Language: en
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 005k^VHv4tjFk3tpscL6iX0003u3000QWJ
Date: Fri, 14 May 2021 10:36:44 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

**Request:**

POST /OA_HTML/OA.jsp?page=/oracle/apps/pos/orders/webui/PosVpoMainPG&_ri=177&OASF=POS_PURCHASE_ORDERS&OAMC=75556_101_0&searchType=advancedSearch&fwkQBSearchTypeSource=/oracle/apps/pos/orders/webui/PosVpoMainPG__QueryRN__177&fwkST/oracle/apps/pos/orders/webui/PosVpoMainPG__BuyerQueryRN__177=search&_ti=929717154&retainAM=Y&addBreadCrumb=N&oapc=5&oas=y3U6e-azV0PHjxYBLKMvDQ.. HTTP/1.1
Host: ***.***.***.***
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2902
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: https://***.***.***.***
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: https://***.***.***.***/OA_HTML/OA.jsp?page=/oracle/apps/pos/orders/webui/PosVpoMainPG&_ri=177&retainAM=Y&addBreadCrumb=Y&OASF=POS_PURCHASE_ORDERS&_ti=929717154&oapc=3&OAMC=75556_101_0&menu=Y&oaMenuLevel=1&oas=FXTm_3QlqF_Y-Y8VlofoRw..
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: oracle.uix=0^^GMT+1:00^p; AWSELB=A783D50F14CF4CBB226BB1C058EBEB456B00B3D67E02A02EBD603D1E154EED054041A5E035215817A86707A77A58A4991D2CA403597186BAF51C3F02BEFF3C7F59E02F2B86; AWSELBCORS=A783D50F14CF4CBB226BB1C058EBEB456B00B3D67E02A02EBD603D1E154EED054041A5E035215817A86707A77A58A4991D2CA403597186BAF51C3F02BEFF3C7F59E02F2B86; PRAPPROD=41Z0Kgq6FeMIiAQfJgdtxD5Uh7; JSESSIONID=efNqcXC2tihLES4kEVkXkS0N9RN9-zYry07mua93zUdB9l5p1QJN!2094438691; treemenu1=none open

Do I try to replicate the onClick submitForm function with a post?

Comment: Your question is very vague! You need to offer more detail and context. All I can understand is that you want to find a download link from HTML. You need to understand that the person reading your question might not have the same background and context as you do, and you need to provide that.

Comment: I want to find the download link that is generated by the server. The link will be used in a http get request. I've inspected the network analysis tool and I can't find the url/link.